# Sql Query keeps getting error: Timeout

Tags: mysql, visual-studio

What im trying to accomplish with this query is a Count by DAY of SR_AREA with INS_Product and Resolution_CD for 3/1/2016 to 3/31/2016

How do I get the Timeout function to work in my code below. I tried the

```
SqlCommand comm= new SqlCommand();
comm.CommandTimeout = 120
```

and its not working. How can I get this to work?

```
SELECT SR_AREA, INS_PRODUCT, RESOLUTION_CD, CREATED AS DATEADD, COUNT(*) AS DAY
FROM S_SRV_REQ
WHERE (dbo.fn_dstoffset(CREATED) >= @STARTDATE) AND (dbo.fn_dstoffset(CREATED) <= DATEADD(D, 1, @ENDDATE))
GROUP BY INS_PRODUCT, RESOLUTION_CD, SR_AREA, CREATED
```

Comment: please show us the EXPLAIN if your query to see what happend

Comment: Please show us 1) what you are setting the CommandTimemout too 2) How you are executing the SQL 3) What your expected outcome is